# How can I pass data to my app when launching from a link?

Tags: flutter

I am making an app in Flutter, and I want to allow the user to click a link from an email per say, and give the app some data to know which view to load up.

I cannot find if this is possible in flutter. Maybe I am not looking for the right terminology. Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried looking for:

- "send data to app on launch",
- "send data to app from link",
- "app launch parameters"

and other similar phrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this plugin, it indroduce how to use app link and deep link in flutter, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Also for anyone else looking firebase also has a package that can help with this, they call it dynamic links. Both packages are good choices.